# How do you invert a tensor of boolean values in Pytorch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

With NumPy, you can do it with np.invert(array), but there's no invert function in Pytorch. Let's say I have a 2D tensor of boolean values:

```
import torch

ts = torch.rand((10, 4)) < .5
```

```
tensor([[ True,  True, False,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True, False,  True,  True],
        [False,  True,  True, False],
        [False,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True, False,  True,  True],
        [False,  True, False,  True],
        [ True,  True, False,  True],
        [False, False,  True, False]])
```

How do I transform the False into True and vice versa?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Literally just use the *tilde* to transform all `True` into `False` and vice versa.

```
ts = ~ts
```